# Finding common elements in a few lists out of all lists in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following lists in my code:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [2,3,5,7,9]
l3 = [4,9,11,12,13]
l4 = [1,2,5,7,8]
l5 = [1,3,4,5,9]
```

And I want the output such that it includes elements common in 3 out of the given 5 lists, in this case:

```
op = [1,2,3,4,5,9]
```

Can I get any help with this? Thanks.

Comment: SO is not meant as a free code writing service. We help with specific problems that you encounter while programming and which you have already tried to solve yourself. Consequentially, all questions asked here must demonstrate some research effort and/or attempted solutions. After that, we will be more than happy to help.

Comment: What is wrong with simply looping through the elements and checking if the other lists contain the element? Might not be uber efficient, but if the lists are small, the time taken would be insignificant.

Comment: @iCodez sadly, but there will be always some reputation collectors who would be eager to solve any question hoping to get some useless points.

Comment: …or trying to help a novice.  Seriously, what do you expect to achieve if you welcome new users like this?

Comment: @user3426575 - We expect to maintain the quality of the content here.  All users, regardless of experience, reputation, age, etc. must follow the guidelines for asking questions as outlined in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  Those who encourage misconduct in an effort to simply gain reputation undermine the purpose of this site.

Comment: @user3426575 - Also, I do not want you to think that we are being harsh or mean.  We are really trying to help.  Poor questions are often subject to downvotes and other penalties.  We don't want you to experience this, so we inform you of the rules.  My comment was meant as a word of caution, not a condemnation.

Comment: Sorry that it seemed as if I wanted to just copy the code, but I just wanted to find the logic and this was bugging me for quite a while.

Comment: Maybe I'm biased with this, but my first question on SO got downvoted for no apparent reason.  This is something I've seen too often.  We can't expect users to have the kind of problems we want to answer—it's the other way round.

Comment: @iCodez Too late, someone already did his homework. SO is kind of a defacto "writes codes for you" place, given how often these questions get answered instead of rejected. +1 for Consequentially tho.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because StackOverflow is not a code-generation service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ok ?

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l2 = [2,3,5,7,9]
>>> l3 = [4,9,11,12,13]
>>> l4 = [1,2,5,7,8]
>>> l5 = [1,3,4,5,9]
>>> all = l1 + l2 + l3 + l4 + l5
>>> c = [[x,all.count(x)] for x in set(all)]
>>> [x[0] for x in c if x[1] > 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
>>>
```

Updated as @TessellatingHeckler mentioned in the comment:

```
>>> all = sum([ list(set(x)) for x in (l1,l2,l3,l4,l5) ],[])
>>> c = [[x,all.count(x)] for x in set(all)]
>>> [x[0] for x in c if x[1] > 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: At the moment it works, but if any of l1 through l5 contain repeat numbers, it can't tell whether a number was seen in three different lists, or three times in one list. I'd do `all = set(l1)+set(l2)...` to counter that.

Answer (score 2):

```
m = {}
for l in [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5]:
    for x in l:
        try:
            m[x] += 1
        except KeyError:
            m[x] = 1

op = []
for x in m:
    if m[x] >= 3:
        op.append(x)
```